# is PLA gasoline, diesel or chemical resistant?

Tags: pla, abs, print-material

can PLA be used to print out containers or other parts that are in direct contact with gasoline, diesel or other hard chemical substances? Will it start degrading when in contact with said chemicals? Should I use ABS for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used both ABS and PLA for diesel gas caps and oil plugs.  As well have made a gasoline funnel out of both.   Both have done well for me.
I have attach a link to a plastics resistance chart if it is any help.  Unfortunately it does not show testing for ABS for all.

I prefer the ABS only do to the fact some items I have made sit in the desert sun.

[Plastic resistance chart](http://www.plasticsintl.com/plastics_chemical_resistence_chart.html)

Comment: do you have experience with below freezing temperatures and using PLA for gasoline/diesel?

Comment: Only with the oil plug and the diesel tank cap as I have sent those types of items to my son and he live in areas where it freezes.   As for the funnels no experience with the cold.  But I will note I have had commercially made plastic gas cans and funnels in freezing weather and had them break do to the cold.  But no issues with the petroleum itself affecting them.